# Idiomatic way of rendering style info using Clojure Hiccup

Tags: css, clojure, hiccup

I need to build style info within hiccup in order to place an element at a location indicated by the variables "top" and "left". My code looks like so:

> (html [:div {:style (str "top" top ";left" left)}
>        "some text"])

This code is pretty ugly. It would be nicer if hiccup automatically rendered the "style" attribute using standard CSS style rules... Then I could write the following:

> (html [:div {:style {:top top :left left}}
>        "some text"])

Is there already a library that does this? Or, do I need to roll my own solution?

Thank you Clojurians for any pointers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could write a function that would do that, and it would even be slightly less typing than the map. For example:

```
(defn style [& info]
  {:style (.trim (apply str (map #(let [[kwd val] %]
                                   (str (name kwd) ":" val "; "))
                                (apply hash-map info))))})
```

Which would allow you to write it like this...

```
(html [:div (style :top top :left left) "some text"])
```

Sample output from the function...

```
user=> (style :top 32 :left 14)
{:style "top: 32; left: 14;"}
```

Comment: Thanks Bill- I think it's clear from the few responses to this question that "rolling your own solution" is the right answer, as you suggest. I asked because I am creating a clojure library that adds this feature and wanted to make sure I wasn't "reinventing the wheel".

Comment: @drcode I just realized who you are. I have Land of Lisp and I love it. Thanks!

Comment: Coming across this 3 years later... the code after (name kwd) should be ":" not an empty space to be valid css syntax for any future readers.

Comment: @ScottMitchell So it should be `(str (name kwd) ":" val "; "))` instead of `(str (name kwd) " " val "; "))` ?

Comment: Yea I just used your snippet for an email thing ;)

Comment: @ScottMitchell Fixed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
(defn style [s]
  (str/join ";" (map #(str (name %) ":" ((keyword %) s)) (keys s))))

(style {:padding     "20px"
        :background  "#e68a00"
        :color       "white"
        :font-size   "large"
        :font-weight "bold"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much into Clojure yet, but a 'transformation' based approach like that of Enlive sounds like the solution for these kind of needs - 
https://github.com/cgrand/enlive